Read semantic information from modifier in Jetpack Compose
I am wondering if it is possible to read the testTag or other semantics from a Modifier at runtime.
I know it is possible via the ComposeContentTestRule, but I want to do it in my code to dynamically name my test tags regarding the names of "parent" composables.
For example, I want to name the testTag of the 10th item in my song list like this:
songList_genreView_listItem10. When I use the same composable on another screen, it could then have this name: pictureList_listItem3 without the need of setting this manually.
So my idea is to use the Modifier passed to the composable function and read out some informations from it and then apply the new name.
Any ideas how I could achieve this?

It is not possible to directly read the testTag from a Modifier at runtime, but here is a way to create and pass the dynamic test tags to down from parent.
@Composable
fun Parent(
    type: String,
    itemList: List<String>
) {
    LazyColumn {
        itemsIndexed(itemList) { index, item ->
            Child(
                type = type,
                index = index,
                item = item)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Child(
    type: String,
    index: Int,
    item: String) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .testTag("${type}_listItem$index")
    ) {
        Text(text = item)
    }
}


Yes, I had hope that I do not need to pass any additional parameters for this to my composable functions.

Sorry, semantic properties like testTag are only accessible during UI tests with ComposeContentTestRule and cannot be accessed at runtime, even with reflection.

Here (https://blog.bitdrift.io/post/implementing-session-replay-android-compose) is an interesting article of someone who tried to and it seems they found a solution (in the end of the article), but unfortunately I do not really understand how they get access to the semantics node via AndroidComposeView.

Looks interesting i don't know. It looks like they did a lot of R&D on this. Why not check with the SDK owner?

@KCD Adding Modifier parameter to Child Composable instead of index would be sufficient.
